# MS Outlook accept meeting multiple times

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

**Is there a way to avoid accepting a meeting a second or third time?**

Short explanation:

In our Company, we use MS Office 365 including now MS Outlook with Exchange Online.

If Adam sends Bob an **invitation** for a **meeting**, Bob may accept this invitation directly via the **message** he receives in his Mail-Inbox or on the respective entry in the **calendar**. In either way, if Bob does so, Adam **receives** a short **message** notifying him that Bob accepted and (hopefully) will attend the meeting. #

BUT - Here comes the issue

Even if Bob **already** accepted the invitation, he still can go to his calendar, select the meeting and click "Accept" once again - and again, and again.

*And now every time Bob hits that sweet "Accept"-Button, Adam will receive yet another message notifying him of Bob's acceptance - wondering if Bob just wants to annoy him or if he's suffering from dementia.*

*Bob will surely deny this and Adam calls IT to ask why he constantly receiving those emails and how to stop this utter nonsense.*

So: Is there a way to **disable** the "Accept" button after the meeting has already been accepted?

Or

can we at least **avoid** Adam from **receiving** any followup replies?

***EDIT***

AFAIK the only solution aka workaround would indeed be to automatically process all incoming updates for meetings, which would also include the **first** response to a meeting.

Comment: Yes. Although meeting was accepted, we can still click Accept button. Currently, there is no option in Outlook to prevent receiving followup replies.

Comment: I think Adam can set to automatically process meeting requests and responses as a workaround:
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/change-how-outlook-processes-read-receipts-and-meeting-responses-3e18ef46-57c0-4e49-ad89-b44ae75596ed